# Why Drupal Commerce 2 Installs in a Sub Directory

Tags: commerce, composer

Why Drupal Commerce 2 Installs in a subdirectory ? Is there any way we can install that in public_html directory so website can be accessed directly through domain ?

Edit

let me try to clear my question. Actually when we setup commerce 2 through

composer create-project drupalcommerce/project-base mystore --stability dev

it setups the site in mystore directory so if I need to access my site I will need to enter this url mydomain.com/mystore

what I want to know if it's possible to install Drupal commerce 2 directly in public_html directory ??

Comment: What do you mean by "installs in a subdirectory"? Drupal Commerce is a module, it has to be installed in a subdirectory, but that doesn't affect where your web root is located

Comment: @Clive I have tried to clear my question. May be that make some sense now :)

Comment: It does, but it's still unclear why you would need to ask this. Look at the statement you ran, you told it to go in a folder called `mystore`. If you didnt' want to do that, why did you do that?

Comment: I actually just want to know if it is possible to install directly in public_html

Comment: Alright actually it was giving me some error when I was replacing mystore with . to install that in current directory

composer create-project drupalcommerce/project-base . --stability dev

Finally I find out that it was due to some hidden files in that directoy which made me think that it is not possible to install commerce 2 in root directory

Answer (score 0):

`composer create-project drupalcommerce/project-base $PROJECTFOLDER --stability dev` installs Drupal and Drupal Commerce. It's a composer [project template](https://github.com/drupalcommerce/project-base).

The webroot than is $PROJECTFOLDER/web. You have to adjust your webserver configuration to point to to correct webroot. You shouldn't install your entire project to an "public" public_html folder.